# AndroidStudio Java Message after checking a box

Tags: java, android, checkbox, toast

I am trying to display a message when I check a box. The problem is that the message is not shown. If I start the application with the box checked by default, the message will just be shown at the beginning and if I try to uncheck and check again, it won't appear again. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CheckBox checkBox;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        if (checkBox.isChecked())
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Box was checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: in any "UI toolkit" (Windows forms, AWT, SWT, etc.) you always have to "signup for some event" .... not just checking value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a listener for your checkbox in order to handle its clicks. Remove this line

```
 if (checkBox.isChecked())
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Box was checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And use this code:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Box was checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Box was unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: I have 1 more question. Why my code won't work? The If statement is pretty clear, so what is wrong about it? I think I am missing something important

Comment: In your code you are asking your widget if it is checked and it is answering you: "Yes I'm checked" and that's all.
 But if you want to track any input between the user and the checkbox you need to implement a listener (an interface to capture the callbacks from the views) in order to capture this.
Here you can understand better what I am trying to show you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Comment: Let me know if you have understood it. If it is ok, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a listener on a checkbox.

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){})
```